# How to cancel a request

Tags: async-await, odata, simple.odata

I am using the [Simple.OData.Client](https://github.com/object/Simple.OData.Client) library, and I need to be able to cancel a request before it completes. None of the `async` methods accept a `Cancelation-Token`. Am I missing something?

Comment: Maybe, ["How do I cancel non-cancelable async operations?"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/10/05/how-do-i-cancel-non-cancelable-async-operations.aspx)

Comment: Async call need support by OData service. I think your service maybe not implement async now.

Comment: Hi John, I will look into the implementation and will get back to you. I may need to extend the API to accept cancellation token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just pushed to NuGet Simple.OData.Client pre-release 3.0.0-rc2 that adds support for cancellation tokens, so you can try it or wait until the final 3.0 is released (in a couple of weeks).